# Commutant of algebra of multiplication operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $L^2(X)$ be the set of Lebesgue square-integrable functions on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. Define $\mathfrak{A}:=\{M_f:f\in L^{\infty}(X), f=\overline{f}\}$, where $M_f$ is the the multiplication operator on $L^2(X)$ defined by $M_f(g)=fg$. In particular all elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ are self-adjoint since $M_f^*=M_{\overline{f}}$. I know, if one omit the property $f=\overline{f}$, that $\mathfrak{A}=\mathfrak{A}'$ (hence $\mathfrak{A}$ is its own commutant and hence a von Neumann algebra). But what can be said about our $\mathfrak{A}$? Is it also a von Neumann algebra? Whats about $\mathfrak{A}'$? Someone an idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your $\mathfrak A$ is basically $L^\infty(X,R)$ (the real bounded, measurable functions on $X$) acting on $L^2(X) =L^2(X,\mathbb R) + i L^2(X,\mathbb R)$. It is not a von Neumann algebra because von Neumann algebras are closed under multiplication by complex scalars and your $\mathfrak A$ is not. This suggests that it is a [real von Neumann algebra](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54898/what-is-the-right-definition-of-real-von-neumann-algebra)?

Comment: @TomCooney Thanks a lot. Because I want to formulate the proposition $5.3.2$ in Pedersen's "Analysis Now" for self-adjoint operators not for normal operators. Do you have an idea how to solve this? Because my $\mathfrak{A}$ is not the good manner to do this (I thought you have only to use real-valued functions).

Comment: First of all, Proposition 5.3.2 in Pedersen is about unbounded operators and $\mathfrak A$ contains only bounded operators. But $\mathfrak A$ is just the set of self-adjoint operators $\mathfrak M_{sa}$ in the von Neumann algebra $\mathfrak M = \{M_f: f\in L_\infty(X)\}$ and, yes, there is a bijection between $\mathfrak M_{sa}$ and the real-valued functions in $L_\infty(X)$. This bijection is the restriction of the $*$-isomorphism between $\mathfrak M$ and $L_\infty(X)$ to their self-adjoint parts, where this bijection is the one guaranteed by the Borel functional calculus (Section 4.5).